# Dynamic Time Warping Similarity Percentage

Tags: algorithm, math, signal-processing

I want the DTW algorithm to output the similarity percentage between 2 arrays of values. I want 0% to mean there's no similarity between signals, and 100% to mean the 2 signals are identical. The modification I thought about is that 100% would be the shortest path from the start to end of the matrix, while 0% would be the path going all the way to the right then all the way up (m+n). The value I want to map to this interval would be the length of the path generated by the DTW algorithm. Would this produce accurate results, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully studying the algorithm, it turned out that minimum cost path will always lie on the diagonal of the matrix. This means that the modification I suggested above for calculating the similarity percentage, will not work.